# Preserving passed-in query string when authorizing facebook app using OAuth 2.0?

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

I have a facebook app using OAuth 2.0, and I'd like to add some tracking. Namely, I'd be having users access certain URLs, which I'd handle on the server side.

If the user has already authorized the app, `http://apps.facebook.com/APP?referrer=test` will be parsed correctly.

If not, however, the user gets sent to the authorization page, which completely removes the query string. When they get sent back to the app later, there is no query string.

If there any way to preserve these values across a facebook authentication?